# Uploading multiple files using jsp

Tags: jsp, file-upload

I am creating a website where the users can upload photos,videos and also write or create posts.It's almost like a blog.I am using JSP.I have used "multipart/form data".But I am facing a problem.Whenever the user is clicking on the submit button,all the photos and videos cannot be uploaded at the same time.Besides,since I am using "multipart/form data" I cannot retrieve the values by request.getParameter() in the next page.So what should I do?I searched across many websites and found a code on uploading which included Disk and Iterator interfaces.But I am having problem in resolving them.Someone help me please.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `request.getParameter()` with a form having `"multipart/form-data"`. Use [FileUploa](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/)d  API (Apache commons).

Comment: I used FileUpload API(Apache commons).But as I said I am having problems with resolving.It's giving me errors.

Answer (score 1):

> *Whenever the user is clicking on the submit button,all the photos and videos cannot be uploaded at the same time.*

This cannot be true. This problem is caused by something else. Perhaps you're using JavaScript to submit the form on a click/change of the file field, or you are misinterpreting the process at the server side.

---

> *Besides,since I am using "multipart/form data" I cannot retrieve the values by request.getParameter() in the next page.So what should I do?*

Use the same API as you have used to parse the uploaded file (you **did** use one, right?). That very same API should be able to give you those parameters back from the `multipart/form-data`  body.

#### See also:

- [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824)

Comment: I am using Javascript but not for submitting the form.By Javascript I am dynamically increasing the number of fields and clearing the fields.